# document.ElementById triggers wrong Object

Tags: javascript, html, css, triggers

I have tried to change the class of an object via JS so that i can change CSS styling with onclick="document.getElementByID…"

```
<div class="box2"      onClick="document.getElementById('hidegetstartedcontainer').id = 'showgetstartedcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-noblur').id = 'pagecontainer-blur'">
<span id=red>GET </span></br>
<span id=redbold>STARTED</span> 
</div>

<div class="box4" onClick="document.getElementById('hidegetintouchcontainer').id = 'showgetintouchcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-noblur').id = 'pagecontainer-blur'">
<span id=redbold>GET IN TOUCH</span></br>
<span id=red>WITH US</span> 
</div>
```

Triggering the above does work as expected.
Now in the showgetstartedcontainer as well as in showgetintouchcontainer i have a close button that should trigger reverse:

```
<div id="hidegetstartedcontainer">
<div class="close1" onclick="document.getElementById('showgetstartedcontainer').id = 'hidegetstartedcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-blur').id = 'pagecontainer-noblur'"></div>
</div>

<div id="hidegetintouchcontainer">
<div class="close2" onclick="document.getElementById('showgetintouchcontainer').id = 'hidegetintouchcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-blur').id = 'pagecontainer-noblur'"></div>       
</div>
```

Expected is: .close1 triggers #showgetstartedcontainer
.close2 triggers #showgetintouchcontainer

Result is: .close1 triggers #showgetintouchcontainer as well as close2

Since triggering from #showgetintouchcontainer does happen without triggering the other way around first, so that showgetintouchcontainer does not exist, an error occures "null is not an object".

Why is .close1 triggering the wrong object? Any help is appreciated.

cheers

Comment: id should be unique in same document.

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique in same document, try to replace the duplicatd ids by global class.

Better if you avoid the inline-events, and write function in your js instead :

```
<div class="box2" onClick="document.getElementById('hidegetstartedcontainer').id = 'showgetstartedcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-noblur').id = 'pagecontainer-blur'">
  <span class=red>GET </span><br/>
  <span class=redbold>STARTED</span> 
</div>

<div class="box4" onClick="document.getElementById('hidegetintouchcontainer').id = 'showgetintouchcontainer'; document.getElementById('pagecontainer-noblur').id = 'pagecontainer-blur'">
  <span class=redbold>GET IN TOUCH</span><br/>
  <span class=red>WITH US</span> 
</div>
```

**NOTE :** Better if you avoid the inline-events, and create events in your js instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but i don´t see any non unique IDs in here. Can you explain a little further please?

Comment: Just fixed it myself, problem was in the CSS file;)